# Move azure storage account to different region

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We mistakenly set up an azure storage account in the wrong location West Europe.
However we need it to be in North Europe.

Is there a way to transfer a whole storage account. 
We don't really need the old data in the container.

But if we just delete the account and recreate in new location it will generate a new access keys, which we don't want.

Is there anyway to either manually set the access keys on a new storage account or move the storage account between regions.

Either solution works for us, moving it or deleting it and recreating with same access keys, but we can't have the new storage account with different access keys.  We don't care whether or not the data comes across.

I can't see a way of setting access keys in web portal, maybe this is possible programmatially but I've searched and can't see anyone else with samples of this.

Comment: Landed here from Google. Based on my searching, there still isn't a way to do this. Here's a link to a relevant [Azure feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/19224478-change-geographical-region-for-a-given-resource) that people can vote for in the hopes that Microsoft will notice and add this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might get closed due to it being an Azure infrastructure, vs. programming, question (and would fit better on ServerFault), though it could be argued that, since you need keys to access storage from your code (or via Azure SDKs), it's "close" to programming-related.

That said: You can't just move a storage account. You'll need to delete and re-create, which will give you new keys. You cannot provide your own keys, so you cannot copy keys from your old storage account to your new storage account.

Regarding the API (and portal, and SDK's, and PowerShell cmdlets, all built upon the API): The API only allows you to trigger a re-generation of either primary or secondary key. There's no way to pass in your own key.

Comment: We are pretty much snookered then, I was hoping there would be a way to programmatically set the keys, as I know you can't do it via the web portal.

Comment: Is there any way I can move this question to ServerFault? I've updated to also ask about programmatically changing it.

Comment: @DermFrench I've voted to move to ServerFault, if 3 other people do also then it'll automatically move